# Every PHP error causes an nginx 500 error instead of showing PHP error data

Tags: php, nginx, laravel-valet

I get a 502 server error from nginx on every PHP request that has an error in it. This is what shows up in the nginx log for every type of error:

```
[error] 394#0: *7 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: example.test, request: "GET /nova-api/users/lens/example-lens?search=&filters=W3siY2xhc3MiOiJBcHBcXE5vdmFcXEZpbHRlcnNcXExlbnNVc2VyRmlsdGVyIiwidmFsdWUiOnsiY29sdW1uIjoiMCIsIm9wZXJhdG9yIjoiPSIsImRhdGEiOiJoYXJ2ZXkifX1d&orderBy=&orderByDirection=desc&perPage=25&page=1&viaResource=&viaResourceId=&relationshipType= HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/Users/user/.config/valet/valet.sock:", host: "example.test", referrer: "https://example.test/nova/resources/users/lens/example-lens"
```

If I run the same code on any other system, I actually get a PHP error in my laravel.log file.

I've tried increasing the number of max PHP children.

I've tried completely reinstalling nginx, PHP, and Laravel Valet.

My `valet.conf` nginx file which is auto-generated by Laravel Valet:

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:80 default_server;
    root /;
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 128M;

    location /41c270e4-5535-4daa-b23e-c269744c2f45/ {
        internal;
        alias /;
        try_files $uri $uri/;
    }

    location / {
        rewrite ^ "/Users/user/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/server.php" last;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log "/Users/user/.config/valet/Log/nginx-error.log";

    error_page 404 "/Users/user/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/server.php";

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass "unix:/Users/user/.config/valet/valet.sock";
        fastcgi_index "/Users/user/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/server.php";
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME "/Users/user/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/server.php";
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your nginx confit look like?

Comment: increase php memory limit ini fpm config, cause if php prematurely closes upstream it means php crashing due to lack of resources, which in Your case is not enough memory. also don't put unix socket file to disk file system, put it to `/var/run/php-something.sock`

Comment: I bumped PHP mem limit to 2G and same issue.

Comment: Can you verify that PHP mem limit is 2G at phpinfo?

Comment: If I run `php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit');"` I get 2G.

Comment: If I run `cat /usr/local/etc/php/7.4/php.ini | grep "memory_limit"` I get `memory_limit = 2G`

Answer (score 0):

Manually removing valet by doing `sudo rm -rf /Users/myuser/.config/valet/` and then `valet install` fixed the issue.